# What is the minimum amount of water required to grow carrots/melons at max speed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am going to make a huge melon/carrot farm, 300 x 100 or something similar. How much water (per block?) do I need to fill my area with as many crops as possible but still grow at the max speed?

Comment: I don't believe wheat works the same way as melons and carrots do @Aequitas.

Comment: Anything that can grow on farmland is counted as a _Crop_

Comment: If I can remember correctly the amount of watering doesn't really matter so much, so long as the block counts as *watered*, which is 4 blocks in any direction. In terms of a field, that's a 9x9 space of field blocks with a single block of water in place of the middle block.